# Is it possible to get filtered and unfiltered lists using only one Java stream?

Tags: java, functional-programming

For learning purposes, imagine I have a list of `User` objects and this object has a gender field that accepts only male or female values. I also have a `isMale()` method based on this field.

I need to split this list into one only with males and the other one just with females. Is this possible using only one stream and, obviously, filter with a predicate or do I have to go back to the good old foreach?

I'm trying to achieve these two lists below, but using only one filtered stream and without foreach command or list method.

```
final var males = users.stream().filter(User::isMale).toList();
final var females = users.stream().filter(u -> !u.isMale()).toList();
```